# Fork/Join: Collecting results

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, fork

I'm playing around with fork/join and thought of the following example:

`App1`: 2 for-loops generating some random numbers into an `ArrayList` and passing it to a `fork`
`MyTask` (Fork): Iterating through the `ArrayLists` and adding up all numbers, then return the value

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class App1 {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    static final ForkJoinPool mainPool = new ForkJoinPool();

    public App1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.clear();
            for (int j = 1000; j <= 100000; j++) {
                int random = 1 + (int)(Math.random() * ((100 - 1) + 1));
                list.add(random);
            }
            mainPool.invoke(new MyTask(list));
        }
        // At the end showing all results
        // System.out.println (result1 + result2 + result3...);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App1 app = new App1();
    }
}


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

public class MyTask extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {

    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    int result;

    public MyTask(ArrayList list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer compute() {
        for(int i=0; i<=list.size(); i++){
            result += (int)list.get(i); // adding up all numbers
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. I also don't know, how to collect all the results from the forks.
Could anybody please have a look at my code?

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error?  Does the actual result differ from the expected result?

Comment: I don't know how to collect the results from all the forks.

Comment: Did you read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html ?

Comment: Of course, I did. But, unfortunately I couldn't extract the information I need.

Comment: `ArrayList` isn't thread-safe. Use something like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

While your code looks fine, you are using ForkJoinPool in a wrong way. This is a tool for tasks that can be split into independent sub-tasks **and** can be increased in speed through multi-threading.

Your task probably isn't big enough to really benefit from multi-threading, but putting that aside since it is a learning exercise, you still need to split the main task into sub-tasks, but all you do is to count the entire array once.

Things you could do in your code:

- Use a different mode of multi-threading that fits better.
- Fork the task and hand over a start and end position inside the array, then sum up the results once those sub-tasks are done.

Since you are probably interested in the later one, here is an example on how to do this:

```
public class MyTask extends RecursiveTask<Integer> {

  final ArrayList<Integer> list;
  final int start, end;

  public MyTask(ArrayList<Integer> list, int start, int end) {
    this.list = list;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
  }

  @Override
  protected Integer compute() {
    if (end - start > 10) { // is this task big enough to justify more threading?
      final int half = (end + start) / 2;
      final MyTask firstHalf = new MyTask(list, start, half);
      final MyTask secondHalf = new MyTask(list, half+1, end);
      invokeAll(firstHalf, secondHalf);
      return firstHalf.get() + secondHalf.get();
    } else {
      int result = 0;
      for(int i=start; i<=end; i++){
        result += list.get(i); 
      }
      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that since coder used `i<=end`, `end` in the first call must be: `list.size() - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the result of `invoke`:

```
Integer result = mainPool.invoke(new MyTask(list));
System.out.println(i + "\t" + result);
```

Comment: Doing so I get a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: On which line do you get this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend `RecursiveAction` or `RecursiveTask` according to you need whether you need to return something or not.

In both the classes you need to override the following function:

```
protected abstract void compute();//in RecursiveAction
protected abstract V compute(); //in RecursiveTask
```

Below is the modified quick sort. Please observe this and try implementing your self:

```
public class ForkJoinQuicksortTask extends RecursiveAction {
    static final int SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD = 10000;

    private final int[] a;
    private final int left;
    private final int right;

    public ForkJoinQuicksortTask(int[] a) {
        this(a, 0, a.length - 1);
    }

    private ForkJoinQuicksortTask(int[] a, int left, int right) {
        this.a = a;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {
        if (serialThresholdMet()) {
            Arrays.sort(a, left, right + 1);
        } else {
            int pivotIndex = partition(a, left, right);
            ForkJoinQuicksortTask  t1 = new ForkJoinQuicksortTask(a, left, pivotIndex-1);
            ForkJoinQuicksortTask t2 = new ForkJoinQuicksortTask(a, pivotIndex + 1, right);
            t1.fork();
            t2.compute();
            t1.join();
        }
    }
    int partition(int[] a, int p, int r){
        int i=p-1;
        int x=a[r];
        for(int j=p;j<r;j++){
            if(a[j]<x){
                i++;
                swap(a, i, j);
            }
        }
        i++;
        swap(a, i, r);
        return i;
    }

    void swap(int[] a, int p, int r){
        int t=a[p];
        a[p]=a[r];
        a[r]=t;
    }

    private boolean serialThresholdMet() {
        return right - left < SEQUENTIAL_THRESHOLD;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ForkJoinPool fjPool = new ForkJoinPool();
        int[] a=new int[3333344];
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            int k=(int)(Math.random()*22222);
            a[i]=k;
        }
        ForkJoinQuicksortTask forkJoinQuicksortTask=new ForkJoinQuicksortTask(a, 0, a.length-1);
        long start=System.nanoTime();
        fjPool.invoke(forkJoinQuicksortTask);
        System.out.println("Time: "+ (System.nanoTime()-start));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `RecursiveTask` not the right way. You have to call the task recursive, take a look at a possible solution below.

So in the end all work is splitted in portions that are `< THRESHOLD`, recursively.

**Update:**

You might want to take a look at [Java Concurrent Animated](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaconcurrenta/), just download the jar and execute it, it has a nice visual explanation how things work.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveTask;

public class RecursiveListSum {

  private static class RecursiveSum extends RecursiveTask<Long> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final int THRESHOLD = 1000;
    private final List<Integer> list;
    private final int begin;
    private final int end;

    public RecursiveSum(List<Integer> list, int begin, int end) {
      super();
      this.list = list;
      this.begin = begin;
      this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
      final int size = end - begin;
      // if the work to be done is below some threshold, just compute directly.
      if (size < THRESHOLD) {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = begin; i < end; i++)
          sum += list.get(i);
        return sum;
      } else {
        // split the work to other tasks - recursive (that's why it is called recursive task!)
        final int middle = begin + ((end - begin) / 2);
        RecursiveSum sum1 = new RecursiveSum(list, begin, middle);
        // invoke the first portion -> will be invoked in thread pool
        sum1.fork();
        RecursiveSum sum2 = new RecursiveSum(list, middle, end);
        // now do a blocking! compute on the second task and wait for the result of the first task.
        return sum2.compute() + sum1.join();
      }
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // First fill the list
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    long expectedSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      int random = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * ((100 - 1) + 1));
      list.add(random);
      expectedSum += random;
    }
    System.out.println("expected sum: " + expectedSum);

    // now let the RecursiveTask calc the sum again.
    final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
    final RecursiveSum recursiveSum = new RecursiveSum(list, 0, list.size());
    long recSum = forkJoinPool.invoke(recursiveSum);
    System.out.println("recursive-sum: " + recSum);
  }

}
```

Comment: What are these `begin` and `end` about?

Comment: `begin` and `end` describe a range that is to be computed by a task. So the actual List is splitted into different sub-sections. Since every task shares the same list, you have to tell the task on what part of the list he has to do it's work.

Comment: I have added a link that might be helpful, it's a nice visual overview how things work.